# Ionic use Stripe Checkout, second time launch Stripe return error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

So I try to use the Stripe Checkout box on my Ionic App. It looks nice on mobile. I use the custom integration. There is a button in my view:

```
<button class="button button-small button-flat button-balanced" ng-click="payStripe(selectedTask.total)">Pay</button>
```

When click, it trigger payStripe function as follow in my controller:

```
$scope.payStripe = function(amount) {
        var chargeAmount = amount * 100;
        console.log ("Pass in amount: " + chargeAmount);  
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: '[stripe key]',
                token: function(token) {

                  $http({
                        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/charge",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                            stripeToken: token.id,
                            amount: chargeAmount,
                        }
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        console.log("Status code: " + status);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        console.log("Status code: " + status);
                    });
                }
            });
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
          name: 'hughdesign.net',
          description: '2 widgets',
          amount: chargeAmount
        });
    }
```

I also included the  in my index.html. I run it on iOs simulator. Everything works nicely at the first try and the charge is successful. After my server return a 204 and the Stripe Checkout pop up close in my app. I want to open it again by clicking the button, it throw error now:

```
Error: Unable to communicate with Checkout. Please contact support@stripe.com    if the problem persists.
sendMessage@https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:48617
https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:15530
https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:47580
ready@https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:47850
invoke@https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:47521
https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:15530
close@https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2:52386
https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2:16468
open@https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:2:34640
```

And this happen to all my other views which contain this button (all trigger the same function). Why it works ONLY ONCE and then stop working? The app did communicated with checkout at the first time checkout...Please help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Execute this code after the popup closes:

```
  delete window.StripeCheckout
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
  document.body.appendChild(script)
```

It's more of a hack than a fix.  I placed this code in the controller that contained the `StripCheckout` object.

Comment: One of the devs on #stripe's IRC channel advised against using Checkout.js in a cordova app: "10:24 AM <•koopajah> We had lots of issues trying to support Cordova app (And webviews in general) so we don't do that anymore. We advise you to build your own form via Stripe.js instead"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you didnt add the certificates that comes with the stripe library into your server..
There is a folder called data with a certificate file. You have to add that folder into your server too.

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing  key: '[stripe key]', to  key: 'stripe key'